# How to ignore GEOS intersection error in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, geos

Basically I have a query/view which extracts data from many different layers. I would post it here but it actually has almost 2000 lines. Queries go something like

```
select a.id
(select count(*) from pointtable2 b where st_contains(a.geom,b.geom ) )
(select sum(st_length(st_intersection(a.geometry, r.geometry))) from linetable3 b where st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom ) and st_isvalid(b.geom) is true ),
(select a whole bunch of stuff from several other tables where multitude of conditions..)
from polygontable a
group by a.id, a.geom
```

In those lines, it does multiple intersections with other tables to extract different values. Problem is that a few days ago, I started running into the following error

```
SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: GEOSIntersects: IllegalArgumentException: RobustDeterminant encountered non-finite numbers 
ERROR: GEOSIntersects: IllegalArgumentException: RobustDeterminant encountered non-finite numbers
```

Because of this error, the whole export selection does not work. I was able to pinpoint this down to a line layer. possibly due to the fact that invalid geometries have been added to the table. Problem is that this layer is one of the most important ones so I can't just exclude it. On my where condition I actually have 'WHERE st_valid(geom) is true'

Is there a way to ignore this error and calculate all features that don't return an error or even a way to detect the error?

Comment: Are you sure the issue is the source geometry and not the intersection? You can try to do a buffer(0) on the intersection result (and ALSO possibly on the 2 inputs)

Comment: @jgh I tried fixing the geometries now but still getting the error. Could you please elaborate on this buffer?

Comment: it helps with "valid but not perfect" geometries. For example it would add a vertex where the inner ring of a polygon touches the outer ring (and prevents, after an intersection, that the inner ring moves slightly outside of the outer ring, which is invalid)

Comment: @jgh when you meant buffer(0), did you mean this format sum(st_length(st_buffer(st_intersection(a.geometry, r.geometry),0))) 
I just tried and still getting the same error

Comment: yes, and/or on the 2 inputs too (`st_buffer(st_intersection(st_buffer(a.geometry,0), st_buffer(r.geometry,0)),0)`). Else try finding the offending geometry to understand what is wrong/how it can be solved (it's can be pretty fast, doing a few iterations and restricting by 1/2 the IDs of the previous run until a single offending row is found)

Comment: @jgh thanks for your time, my issue seems to have been solved after updating postgresql and postgis to the latest version.